# Configure Nginx with two docker-compose containers (Flask and Django)

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to expose two different address used like APIs. One in Django and the other one in Flask, they are Docker-compose containers.

I need configure Nginx for expose the two containers in two different subdomains.

It is my Nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections  1024;  ## Default: 1024, increase if you have lots of clients
 }    

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
"$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

upstream app {
 server django:5000;
}

upstream app_server {
 server flask:5090;
}

server {
 listen 5090;
 location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
  }
}

server {
 listen 5000;
 location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
 }
 }

}
```

And my production.yml

```
Nginx:
  build: ./compose/production/nginx
  image: *image
  ports:
    - 80:80
  depends_on:
    - flask
    - django
```

My containers are all up.

[image]

Comment: Well you are telling `nginx` to run on port 80 then you have `server` blocks listening on port 5000 with no `server_name`. So if this is your actual config then yes you would be having some trouble.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So, Where I must to change the ports? Because If I change ports in production.yml and replace 80:80 by 5090:5090 I have a error.

Comment: ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint core_nginx_1 (7b49e70c117f45cf00fde7488626897a22657cdf73ac9d07d1d546b55986ae7d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5090 failed: port is already allocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `proxy_pass`:

```
server {
    listen <port>;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<container-host-name>:<port>;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    }
}
```

You nginx container connected only with 80 port on machine and 80 port on container, but you nginx server listen `5000` and `5090` ports :)

Comment: I changed the configuration, but not in production.yml because If I replace ports, it response my a error. 

Now, I edited the post with the configuration like your answer, and I have containers working.

Comment: You have an error when you change machine port because `http` use 80 port by default. You can change your container port like 80:5000 or 80:5090. But in this case you will have only one server. I would suggest you to make one server that will be list 5000 port, in production.yml change port to 80:5000, and use different location like /django and /flask. With this configuration when you will have the request like http://<ip>/django it will be proxy to django machine and when http://<ip>/flask to flask machine. But you should to set port for `proxy_pass` too

Comment: Finally, I deleted Flask container. The only reason to use it is because pandas not working in python:alpine. I won't use alpine and I will use python.

Comment: I hope you understand what you need to do if you have two and more containers :)

Comment: Now, I have an other problem, but It is other history: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330761/nginx-up-like-orphan-containers-and-not-working-521-error