# Nginx up like orphan containers and not working (521 error)

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am using a container Nginx with docker-compose, but It have a bad configuration. When I link the domain to 8000 port I have a 521 error.

[image]

It is my Dockerfile:

```
 FROM nginx
 COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I used nginx-alpine, but it not working without alpine python, and I had to change it because Pandas not working with alpine.

So, my nginx.conf is:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections  1024;  ## Default: 1024, increase if you have lots of clients
}

http {
 include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 # fallback in case we can't determine a type
 default_type  application/octet-stream;

 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

 access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

 sendfile        on;
 #tcp_nopush     on;

 keepalive_timeout  65;

 upstream app {
    server django:5000;
 }

server {
# use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
# use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
listen 5000;
charset utf-8;

# Handle noisy favicon.ico messages in nginx
 location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
    access_log     off;
    log_not_found  off;
}

 location / {
    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}

# django app
 location @proxy_to_app {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
    proxy_send_timeout 10080;
    proxy_read_timeout 10080;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_buffers 16 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://app;
}
}
}
```

When I build and up my application, not show any error, and I tip "docker-compose ps" it appear, like the photo, but in some time it disappear, and if I try to do some action with some container, it response:

**WARNING: Found orphan containers (core_nginx_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.**

I tried to make a .env with COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=CORE but not working anyway.

It is my production.yml:

```
nginx:
  build: ./compose/production/nginx
  image: core_production_nginx
  ports:
  - 80:80
  depends_on:
  - django
```

I tried to add 80:5000 but it response me a error.

Answer (score 1):

When your container `disappeared` that means that it down. You can see all containers, upped and down, with command `docker ps -a`. You will find your disappeared container here

When you use command `docker ps` you never see any errors. This command show you only working containers. If you want to see errors inside the container, you should use command `docker logs <container name>`.
And when your container `disappeared` that means that it down. You can see all containers, upped and down, with command `docker ps -a`. You will find your disappeared container here. You should use `docker logs` and you will see why this container down.